# Error en Laravel 419 (Login) en movil, ios, safari

Tags: laravel

de antemano les agradezco la ayuda. Tengo un problema que no sé como resolver y es que cuando ingreso datos de acceso a un login; en Firefox sin problema. Hago la prueba con colocar sólo el usuario y me manda el error de contraseña, hago el intento sin usuario y sin contraseña y me manda el error igual, hasta ahí todo bien y cuando ingreso los 2 datos me manda al lugar deseado. El problema es cuando lo intento desde un móvil o safarí en mac.

Si meto usuario y contraseña correcta: error 419

Si meto usuario y contraseña correcta: error 419

Si meto usuario pero no contraseña: error 419

Si no meto usuario ni contraseña: error 419

Todos los escenarios posibles: Error 419 en equipos moviles, en ios, en safari de mac.

Les dejo un link donde pueden ver el video para hacerme entender mejor
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z7u0fYdZNw3FkiRyLziwFG5AC71jfzSS/view?usp=sharing

Y el error que me marca laravel al final es el siguiente:

```
CSRF token mismatch.

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php#85

 });
        }

        throw new TokenMismatchException('CSRF token mismatch.');
    }

    /**
```

Dejo el código del index.blade.php

```
@extends('Layouts.app')
@section('titulo','Inicio de sesíon')
{{-- @section('subtitulo', 'Inicio de sesíon') --}}
@section('content')

{{-- <h1>Login</h1> --}}

<div class="container">

    <div class="row" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">

        <div class="card">

        <form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        @csrf

            <div class="card-header" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
                <h5>Inicio de sesión</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">

                <div class="row mt-4">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="username" class="col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('Usuario:') }}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i></div>
                        </div>
                        <input  name="username" type="username" id="username" placeholder="Nombre De Usuario" autofocus class="form-control{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                value="{{ old('username') }}">
                        @if ($errors->has('username'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="password" class="col-form-label text-md-left ">{{ __('Contraseña:') }}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password">
                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary botonEspecial">
                        {{ __('Aceptar') }}</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: ¿Y estás enviando el CSRF token con el formulario?

Comment: Creo que si. En la respuesta de abajo te muestro el código amigo. (Teniendo en cuenta que sé pobo sobre laravel)